# Unable to get current user

Tags: flutter, back4app

I am unable to get current user from session in Back4App using flutter.
My variable currentUser is returning a null value.
As per [documentation](https://www.back4app.com/docs/flutter/parse-sdk/users/flutter-current-user) I think I am doing it as they say, but I cannot figure out where could be the error.

```
Future<void> saveTodo(String title, String DogsAge, String breedselection,
    ParseFileBase parseFile) async {

  ParseUser? currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser() as ParseUser?;


  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {});
  final todo = ParseObject('Todo')
    ..set('UserId', currentUser!.objectId)
    ..set('UserMail', currentUser.emailAddress)
```

Comment: Check the previous version of their SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currentUser() returns null if your device is not logged in. Check if there is any login or register option and use and await it first, before calling currentUser().